# Unable to install tensorflowjs: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf-nightly-2.0-preview>=2.0.0.dev20190304

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I was following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_saved_model) in order to create a model that could be interpreted by tensorflowJS.

In the middle of the tutorial, it is asked to install the `tensorflowjs` by executing the following command:

```
pip install tensorflowjs
```

But, in my machine, I'm getting the following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf-nightly-2.0-preview>=2.0.0.dev20190304 (from tensorflowjs) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tf-nightly-2.0-preview>=2.0.0.dev20190304 (from tensorflowjs)

It seems that tensorflowJS has a dependency to `tf-nightly`. So I installed this package by executing the following command:

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

And then again:

```
pip install tensorflowjs
```

But the same error message is throwing to the console.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What operating system and what python version? It is looking for "tf-nightly-2.0-preview" and not "tf-nightly". You can see the list of available packages for each OS and python level here: https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-2.0-preview/#files  (the cpXY is the python level)

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons Python and machine information: Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons If I understand the information correctly, the latest version for windows is for python 3.6 right?

Comment: correct you would need to use python 3.6 to be able to install "tf-nightly-2.0-preview"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advice of [William D.Irons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5879698/william-d-irons) I found out that `tf-nightly` package is not compatible with `python 3.7.x`.

What I did was installing the python 3.6 version (with the add to path option checked) and then executed the following command:

```
pip3.6 install tensorflowjs
```

And the installation was successfully.